# WPF/Prism best way to delete a selected item from a child view from a toolbar button in the Shell?

Tags: wpf, view, command, prism, viewmodel

I'm using WPF/Prism and have a Shell with toolbar in it and a region with a view in it (The view lives in another module).  The view has a treeview in it that is bound to a list of view models.

I have a toolbar button in the Shell I want to have delete the selected treeview item that is in the child region/view.

What is the best way to do this?

I thought about using a command but I'm not sure if there is a way to bind the toolbar button command that lives in the Shell to the view model in the child view (that contains the tree view).  Is this possible/the best way to do this?

The alternatives like using event aggregator to publish the selected item seem plausible or some type of service to publish the selected treeview item to also seem possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a static CompositeCommand in a static class as part of an infrastructure project/dll. Set the toolbar button command property to this command using {x:Static}, and in the viewmodel of the view containing the TreeView you define a local DelegateCommand that you register with the CompositeCommand.

But if the button in the toolbar only applies to this particular view from the module, it would make sense to also define the toolbar as a Prism region and insert the button as a view from the module.

Comment: Thanks this was an interesting possibility to consider using.